# Include null results in group_concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat, isnull, ifnull

I have two tables like this

**profile_answers**

```
+---------+------------+
|      id | class_name |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | Class 1    |
|       2 | Class 2    |
|       3 | Class 1    |
+---------+------------+
```

**educations**

```
+---------+--------------------+------------+
|      id | profile_answers_id |  sample    |
+---------+--------------------+------------+
|       1 | 1                  |     1234   |
|       2 | 1                  |     2334   |
|       3 | 1                  |     3434   |
+---------+------------+--------------------+
```

I ran the query,

```
select educations.profile_answer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(educations.sample) from educations
LEFT JOIN profile_answers ON educations.profile_answers_id = profile_answers.id
```

I got

```
+--------+--------------------+-------------+
|      id | sample                          | 
+---------+--------------------+------------+
|       1 | 1234,2334,3434                  |
+---------+------------+--------------------+
```

I actually want,

```
+--------+--------------------+-------------+
|      id | sample                          | 
+---------+--------------------+------------+
|       1 | 1234,2334,3434                  |
|       2 | NULL                            |
|       3 | NULL                            |  
+---------+------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id,IFNULL(samples,'NULL') sample FROM 
(
    SELECT
        AA.id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT BB.sample) samples
    FROM
        profile_answers AA LEFT JOIN educations BB
        ON AA.id = BB.profile_answers_id
    GROUP BY AA.id
) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing your GROUP BY:

```
select profile_answers.id, GROUP_CONCAT(educations.sample) 
from profile_answers
LEFT JOIN educations ON educations.profile_answers_id = profile_answers.id
GROUP BY profile_answers.id
```

I also altered your JOIN to make the profile_answers table your main table.

Good luck.

Comment: but then, adding group_by caused the execution time of this query very long. some where around 15 seconds for 4000 records

Comment: @ManjunathManohar - You can try leaving it off, but I thought it was needed with GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: leaving it off will give me just the one record

Comment: @ManjunathManohar -- you do need GROUP BY -- see this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dc67/2